# How to check the dropdowncheckboxlist based on database values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dropdownchecklist

I'm using `dropdowncheckboxlist`, where we can select multiple values and my question is how to again check the checkbox inside `dropdownCheckList` based on database values. That is, I have to check multiple values while editing or updating the values. I'm using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dropdown").dropdownchecklist({
            forceMultiple: true
            , onComplete: function (selector) {
                var values = "";
                for (i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++) {
                    if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "") ) {
                        if (values != "") values += ",";
                        values += selector.options[i].value;
                    }
                }
                // alert(values);
                $('#<%= hidVisitorID.ClientID %>').val(values);
            }
            , onItemClick: function (checkbox, selector) {
                 var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");
                 var checkCount = (justChecked) ? 1 : -1;
                 for (i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++) {
                     if (selector.options[i].selected) checkCount += 1;
                 }
                 if (checkCount > 9) {
                     alert("Industry Limit is 9");
                     throw "too many";
                 }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? It looks like [dropdownchecklist isn't compatible with > jquery 1.8](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)

Comment: im using this http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html   link

Comment: Right. That's your `dropdownchecklist` widget source...but what version of jquery are you using? The widget isn't compatible with jquery versions greater than 1.8.

Comment: im using this cdns  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>